# Update uses previously autogenerated ID on Oracle

Tags: sql-server, oracle, nhibernate

We're having a strange problem in Oracle. I'll sketch some (simplified) context first:

Consider this mapping to an Entity:

```
public EntityMap()
{
    Table("EntityTable");
    Id(x => x.Id)
        .Column("entityID")
        .GeneratedBy.Native("ENTITYID").UnsavedValue(0);
    Map(x => x.SomeBoolean).Column("SomeBoolean");
}
```

and this code:

```
var entity = new Entity();
using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
{
    Session.Save(entity);
    transaction.Complete();
}

//A lot of code
if(someCondition)
{            
    using (var transaction = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required))
    {
        enitity.SomeBoolean = true;
        Session.Update(entity);
        transaction.Complete();
    }
}
```

This code is called a few times. The first time it generates the following queries:

```
select ENTITYID.nextval from dual
INSERT INTO Entity
    (SomeBoolean, EntityID)
    VALUES  (0, 1216)
UPDATE Entity
    SET SomeBoolean = 1
    WHERE  EntityID = 1216
```

The second time it is called these queries are generated (`someCondition` is false)

```
select ENTITYID.nextval from dual
INSERT INTO Entity
    (SomeBoolean, EntityID)
    VALUES  (0, 1217)
```

And now the trouble begins. From now on, each insert will use the correct autoincremented value, but the update will always use 1217

```
select ENTITYID.nextval from dual
INSERT INTO Entity
    (SomeBoolean, EntityID)
    VALUES  (0, 1218)
UPDATE Entity
    SET SomeBoolean = 1
    WHERE  EntityID = 1217
```

And of course, this is not what we want to happen. If I inspect the value of the Id while debugging, it contains the correct autoincremented value. Somehow, deep in the bowels of NHibernate, the incorrect is is assigned to the WHERE clause...

The strange part is that this only happens on Oracle. If I switch NHibernate to MsSql, everything works like a charm.

Comment: Hmmm, so something mysterious is happening somewhere in a huge code base which we can;t see.  So what you're asking for is our best guess?

Comment: Not really; Everything relevant is posted here. The 'A lot of code' comment is there to indicate why there are two separate transactions.

Comment: I think this could have something to do with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989150/nhibernate-connection-release-modes-why-does-the-documentation-recommened-using

Answer (score 0):

So I found out what happened. NHibernate changed it's default connection release mode between versions 1.x and 2.x. Instead of closing the connection when the session is Disposed, the connections is now closed after each transaction. However, we were manually coordinating our transactions which apparently caused troubles in Oracle.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1989150/nhibernate-connection-release-modes-why-does-the-documentation-recommened-using) question has some extra information and [this entry in the NHibernate documentation](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#transactions-connection-release) also clarifies how the connections are handeled:

> As of NHibernate, if your application manages transactions through .NET APIs such as System.Transactions library, ConnectionReleaseMode.AfterTransaction may cause NHibernate to open and close several connections during one transaction, leading to unnecessary overhead and transaction promotion from local to distributed. Specifying ConnectionReleaseMode.OnClose will revert to the legacy behavior and prevent this problem from occuring.

[This blog post](http://blog.brianhartsock.com/2009/12/17/nhibernate-connection-release-modes/) is what got me looking in the right direction.

Comment: Are you using the Microsoft Oracle Provider ADO.NET or the one that Oracle (ODP.NET) made?

Comment: It's the Microsoft provider.

Comment: Don't forget to remove the on_close when updating to ODP.NET, the error doesn't occur with that driver.